# Excel downloaded from website are not readable in PHP

Tags: php

```
$path="f.xls";
    require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read($path);
```

This is mycode for just reading excel in PHP

When we trying to read excel which downloaded from any website it showing error that `File is not readable`, **if I open the file and save as in same format** then it gets uploaded successfully and does not give error. 
I tried many excel reader library like `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(),excel_reader.php,excel_reader2.php` but all of them gives same error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Show the code you use to download the CSV from the web

Comment: what's the output of `ls -la` in the directory containing the files?

Comment: How are you able to **save as** a file that you cannot read?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski The libs he's using probably can't read them but Excel can

Comment: @kerbholz: Oh, that wasn't how I read "trying to read excel which downloaded from a website it showing error" lol